# Update sql database with multiple WHERE clauses in java

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I have a database entry that I need to update.

This method obviously doesn't work, but it should help explain what Im trying to do.

```
public void updateEntry(String user, String message, String mentions, String og) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
    args.put(KEY_MENTIONS, mentions);
    this.db.update(ENTRY_TABLE, args, ("message = ?", "username = "+user), new String[] {og});
}
```

I need to update the entry where the "name" column AND the "message" column both match the input values.

The database has multiple entries with the same user, and may have multiple entires with the same message but different user, so multiple where clauses are necessary.

How can I use two (or more) where clauses in an sql query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this change should work..

```
this.db.update(ENTRY_TABLE, args, ("message = ? AND username = "+user), new String[] {og});
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I kept trying &&. I havent used SQL too much so Im not entirely sure of the syntax all the time.

Comment: The more correct way to do this is to also put "username = ?" and put the "user" var in the String array, the way @secretlm suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You can use two (or more) where clauses like:

```
this.db.update(ENTRY_TABLE, args, ("message = ? and Field1 =? and Field2 =? and username = "+user), new String[] {og});
```

The values of Fields is provided by og (array)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
db.rawQuery(your SQL update query);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the Java syntax, but in SQL you can use `AND` to join multiple `WHERE` clauses. Something like this:

```
WHERE message = 'foo' AND username = 'bar'
```